# Is there a circuit where output signal is high ONLY when at a specified input voltage?

Tags: voltage, voltage-measurement

Is there a circuit where the output is high (or on) when the input voltage is at a specific voltage range? For example, if the input voltage is 4.5 V or lower than the circuit output is low (or off). And if the input voltage is 5.5 V or higher than the circuit output is low (or off). However, if the input voltage is between 4.5 V and 5.5 V then the circuit output is high (or on). I've tried various ways using Zener diodes and transistors but keep running into dead ends. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: google window comparitor.

Comment: Try a couple of analog open collector output comparators with their outputs tied together. perhaps an lm393

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for a [window comparator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_detector). It can be implemented easily with a dedicated window comparator IC (like the [TPS3700](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/sbvs187e/sbvs187e.pdf)) or a dual comparator IC (or two single comparators). The two comparators should be open collector (i.e. not push-pull) so that the two outputs don't fight each other. Here's an example from the [TLV170x comparator datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv1702.pdf):

[image]

Since the two thresholds (you're using 4.5 V and 5.5 V) connect to the high impedance inputs of the comparators you don't have to buffer them. You can use a resistor divider, composed of three resistors in order to set two thresholds, from your supply voltage to ground. The datasheet for the aforementioned TPS3700 shows this:

[image]

In the event that the comparator supply voltage \$V_\text{S}\$ is less than your input thresholds you can divide down your the thresholds and your signal to less than \$V_\text{S}\$. For example, if you have \$V_\text{S} = 2\text{ V}\$ then you can divide your 4.5 V and 5.5 V thresholds by, say, 4 -- that would give you thresholds of 1.125 V and 1.375 V.

Comment: ADDITION : Good answer but it assumes Vs > Vin. He may need a divider and a voltage reference device if this needs this to be powered from the same Vin voltage.

Comment: @Trevor Good point. I've added that information.

Comment: That looks suspiciously like a 555.